# JS: how to use anonymous function.bind in addEventListener

Tags: javascript, bind, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

I am coding Hanoi towers and will use eventListeners on canvas (html element). While reading on them I ran the following code from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener),

- Heading - Getting Data Into and Out of an Event Listener
- Sub heading - Getting Data into an Event Listener Using this

```
1 var myButton = document.getElementById('my-button-id');
2 var someString = 'Data';
3
4 myButton.addEventListener('click', function.bind(someString) {
5  console.log(this);  // Expected Value: 'Data'
6 });
```

Why is my outcome `"SyntaxError: missing ( before formal parameters" 4(line):43(column)` - that is where the 'dot' in function.bind stands. Please.

Comment: The MDN use of `function` is a placeholder for _some function they didn't show_.   You need to replace it with a reference to your own function.

Comment: @Alnitak it is not a placeholder because they put the logic after the function declaration, as if it were an anonymous function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function() {
  console.log(this);  // Expected Value: 'Data'
}.bind(someString)
```

Comment: illegal syntax.

Comment: @Alnitak I don't think that's true, it works fine for me

Comment: This is it - your answer encapsulated inside myButton.addEventListener: `myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {console.log(this);}.bind(someString));`
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`bind` is a method found on function objects. It isn't used on the `function` keyword (which forms part of function expressions and function declarations).

First, create the function, *then* bind.

```js
function myFunction () {
    console.log(this);
}

const someString = "something to bind to";

const myBoundFunction = myFunction.bind(someString);

myBoundFunction();
```

Comment: that is nevertheless exactly the code in the MDN page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Getting_Data_Into_and_Out_of_an_Event_Listener :(

Comment: @Alnitak — and now the error on the MDN page is fixed